# splice does not remove element from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

**Edit**

Well, this is indeed embarrassing. Thank you all for noticing the typo, I would have deleted this question, but I can't (because it has answers). Let this be a monument.

I'm trying to write an app which, given an object and an array, removes the object from the array (if it exists), or adds it to the array (if it does not exist).

**Initial array:**

```
var permissions = [{
      id: 3,
      name: "Perm3"
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: "Perm1"
    }];
```

**Add\remove function:**

```
  triggerPermission = function(perm) {
    var idx = permissions.indexOfById(perm);
    if (idx === -1) {
      permissions.push(perm);
    } else {
      permissions.slice(idx, 1); //should have been SPLICE...
    }
  };
```

**helper function:**

```
 Array.prototype.indexOfById = function(obj) {
    var idx = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      if (this[i].id === obj.id) {
        idx = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    return idx;
  };
```

As can be seen on the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/SUdqJMy7gDFKgTQH12fl), I'm trying to use this in an AngularJS app, with checkboxes as triggers. Some permissions are getting returned by `splice` (but the permissions array is not being changed), and some are not even getting returned. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code uses [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), **not** [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

`slice` does not modify the array, it returns a modified copy.

`splice` is the method you are after, which modifies the array in-place.

Answer (score -3):

Exactly what meagar said. Slice will take a part of the array but leave the array untouched. Splice will actually "splice" something off.

Comment: If you post an answer that adds nothing to another answer already posted, just delete the duplicate answer.

Comment: If you would read what I posted then you would realize that I added an explanation. As I can not add comments yet, I posted another answer.